# Providing administrator permission to change rating on mp3s

Tags: windows, windows-11, file-permissions, mp3, windows-11-v22h2

I'm trying to change the rating of mp3s in a Windows 11 environment with Windows Explorer via the Details Pane. It works on some files, but on others, I get this error message:

> You'll need to provide administrator permission to apply properties to this file change.

How ludicrous, Windows. You're barring me from changing an innocuous setting on an mp3. How dare I? *rolling my eyes*

Anyway, I'm a novice at permissions, but I did check a few sites (including this one) that gave a rundown on what I can try. None fit my exact situation (most of what I read was about renaming or deleting files/folders and others were in earlier versions of Windows where the options weren't set up quite the same), but I tried what I could.

I've double-checked that I'm using an administrator account on my computer, though I've also read that doesn't necessarily guarantee anything since the program I'm using to change the rating might not necessarily have admin rights. A few of the sites have led me to go to the Properties dialog, in the Security tab, into the Edit sub-dialog, and changing ownership in there. I've also noted that, under "Permissions for ," all permissions under Allow are clicked except "Special permissions" (not sure if this has any bearing).

In fact, when I try to change the permissions, I get a "File Access Denied" dialog box that says:

> You need permissions to perform this action.
>
> You require permission from <computer name>\<my user account name> to make changes to this file.

So, I need permission from myself?

Can anyone help me change the rating on these mp3s? Seems like such a harmless, mundane function that Windows nevertheless wants to get into a pissing contest over. :/ But what else is new with Windows?

Not sure if this means anything, but here's some other info:

Windows edition: Windows 11 Home
Version: 22H2
Program used: Windows Explorer
Account type: Administrator (verified in Settings->Accounts)

### Mp3 whose permissions I can edit

Screenshot of Security tab (for SYSTEM):

[image]

And after pressing Advanced:

[image]

I went a little further and clicked Add (above Disable Inheritance):

[image]

From the Security tab, here's what I see when I click Edit:

[image]

The box wasn't big enough, but I scrolled down, and Special Permissions was unchecked. It was the only one not checked.

Screenshot of security tab (for my own account):

[image]

When I click Edit, I get the same as SYSTEM: everything under Allow clicked except Special Permissions. (All checkboxes are read only.)

### Mp3 whose permissions I *can't* edit.

Screenshot of Security tab (for SYSTEM):

[image]

And after pressing Advanced:

[image]

I went a little further and clicked Add (above Disable Inheritance):

[image]

From the Security tab, here's what I see when I click Edit:

[image]

Same as above. I scrolled down, and Special Permissions was unchecked. It was the only one not checked.

Screenshot of security tab (for my own account):

[image]

When I click Edit, I get the same as SYSTEM: everything under Allow clicked except Special Permissions. (All checkboxes are read only.)

Comment: [Edit] your question and include the ACL of a file where it is possible to change the attributes and for a file where it’s not possible

Comment: Thanks. Did just that. The permissions look the same for the two files. Is there another dialog box I should dig deeper into?

Comment: How about the Advance ACL? Looking to see if the owner is different between the files. In both cases you have System selected instead of your user which makes your access to the file unclear

Comment: Ok, I added screenshots above for Advanced, Add Permissions, and Edit Permissions above. So far everything looks the same, but maybe you can spot something I can't.

Comment: Your screenshots still show the permissions of System not the permissions of your user

Comment: Oops! Sorry about that. Ok, latest screenshots are in. As far as I can tell, I have the same permissions set as SYSTEM.

Comment: As an Administrator run `TAKEOWN /F "%UserProfile%\Music\testing\"` then run `ICACLS "%UserProfile%\Music\testing\" /grant administrators:F` as sanity check make sure `%UserProfile%\Music\testing\ actually contains the file you want to modify the attributes of.

Comment: Sorry for the long wait for an answer on this. I ran a tool (for a totally unrelated reason) on the files, which seemed to clear up the permissions. Not that I wanted to do that, because I wanted to see if we could find a real answer to this issue (maybe for others). With deep apologies, I'll have to suspend this question until the issue comes back up, but this tool seems to have removed the permissions issue. I'll reopen this question if the issue comes back. Again, deepest apologies for this!